# Java Application Integrating Windows Small Business Server

Tags: java, mysql, windows-sbs

I'm currently writing a client program in Java for my company that will access a mySQL database with customer information.

The company already has a Windows Small Business Server 2011 server with various images and reports related to the customers.

My intention is to store the path of these images into the mySQL database to be recalled from my Java application.

1. I guess my first question is: Is this possible?
2. How do I begin connecting a Java application to SBS in order to access an image file located on the server? Researching online has lead me to believe I can connect Java to SharePoint using a Java -.NET bridge.  Am I heading in the right direction?
3. Is there any issue with installing the mySQL database on the same machine as a SBS?

This is my first time posting on StackOverflow; I apologize if my question format is not focused enough.

This is also my first time working with mySQL and servers.  I've been able to figure out mySQL in Java; but I'd really appreciate a finger pointing in the correct direction with the server.

Answer (score 0):

**1** Yes.

**2** Sounds like a decent approach. You might also consider a Java-COM bridge like [jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/).

**3** Possible issues may include

- Licensing
- Performance impacts
- Memory impacts
- Backup impacts
- Lack of redundancy
- Support
- Implementation complexity
- Storage requirements